# Flutter html render with columns fixed width

Tags: html, flutter, width, render, fixed

I need render from html template a flutter widget:

```
50% | 50% | 100px | 100px
```

In flutter this is simple: 2 Containers in Expanded and 2 Containers whith fixed width, wrapper in Row widget.

I can not find a solution in html, trying lutter_widget_from_html  or flutter_html, no result. I cannot setup fixed width for a right containers. My html template (table with 4 columns):

```
<table border="1" style="padding: 2px; margin: 5px; border: 1px solid red; border-radius: 5px" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>

        <table width="100%">
          <tr>
              <td><div align="left"><b>[offers_no]</b></div></td>
              <td><div align="right"><b>[offers_date]</b></div></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <div align="center"><i>[profsys_name] / [lamtypes_name] / [furnsys_name]</i></div>

        <table width="100%">
          <tr>
              <td><div align="left"><b>[qty] шт.</b></div></td>
              <td><div align="right"><b>[sqr] м.кв.</b></div></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

    </td>

    <td>

        <table width="100%">
          <tr>
              <td><div align="left"><b>[offers_no]</b></div></td>
              <td><div align="right"><b>[offers_date]</b></div></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <div align="center"><i>[profsys_name] / [lamtypes_name] / [furnsys_name]</i></div>

        <table width="100%">
          <tr>
              <td><div align="left"><b>[qty] шт.</b></div></td>
              <td><div align="right"><b>[sqr] м.кв.</b></div></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

    </td>

    <td width="100">
        <a href="{report:report_get_offer_pdf}">
        <center>
        <b>[zsum]</b>
        </center>
        </a>
    </td>

    <td width="100">
        <a href="{report:report_get_offer_pdf}">
        <center>
        <b>[zsum]</b>
        </center>
        </a>
    </td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Html result:  [image]

Flutter result: [image]

Help please

Comment: you need a solution in flutter on in html?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you, Wrap your widgets into **Expanded** or **Flexible** and set to flex. refer **Expanded** class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) , refer **Flexible** class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html), change your flex value on your need.

```
Center(
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(),
            ),
            child: Text('dsagdfghsfghfasgdfhsafdjashdja'),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(),
            ),
            child: Text('dsagdfghsfghfasgdfhsafdjashdja'),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(),
            ),
            child: Text('dsagdfghsfghfasgdfhsafdjashdja'),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(),
            ),
            child: Text('dsagdfghsfghfasgdfhsafdjashdja'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: I need to do it with html templste. Such as HtmlWidget('<table>....')

Comment: ok refer [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)  for that

Comment: Flutter_html also not working